# Reading digital inputs in PC

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, input

I am looking for a way to read digital inputs in my software that is running on a PC.

For an application I use an incremental encoder (line drive RS422) to count the speed of a conveyor belt.

Now I connect the encoder to an Arduino Uno that is reading the digital output of the encoder and "translate" it to a serial signal, so that I can read it with my PC/software.

This works, but is not a solution I like. I prefer to read the digital inputs directly on my PC and translate it there to a readable signal for my software.

Are there solutions to do this and to do it fast? (less than 0.5 ms)

Comment: More direct than USB would more or less limit you to a PCIe DAQ board.

Comment: It's possible to make a cable that is basically a smaller and more specialized version of your Arduino solution. When the board is small enough that it physically appears to be part of the cable or connector, the solution can look cleaner. You may be able to buy premade versions. Try looking for FTDI cables.

Comment: Next define how you want to use this digital readout for a better solution

Comment: Nothing running on a PC can be guaranteed or assumed to happen in less than 0.5ms, unless perhaps it is running in the kernel code.

Comment: It is not clear what about the current solution you don't like. But one option would be to use an acquisition module such as a labjack T4 module to count the pulses and then your software could query the labjack module using the labjack software API. The labjack module can timestamp the data, which may help you deal with whatever latency or timing ciritical issues you have in your application. Your software would use the count and the timestamp to calculate speed of the conveyer.

Answer (score 3):

PCs are not great for meeting real-time requirements, especially if the OS is Windows. It would be easier to meet the real-time requirements with an MCU and transmit the results to the PC.

Counting edges of a quadrature encoder is an example of something that should probably be done with hardware or an auxiliary MCU that may have QEI support hardware on the chip.

Comment: A trivial solution uses the quadrature encoder as a tach with an analog or digital tachometer. It can be made bidirectional too with scaling for poles/rev , the edge just needs to be converted to a pulse equal to the max RPM period for full scale